# Comparison Warning in VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c='w';
    if((c>110 && c>120)&&(c<120 && c<200))
    printf("true");
    else
    printf("false");
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code. The code does give output, but vscode gives me a warning that the comparison of characters with constants(like 200, it specifically shows this only for 200), will always be true, but it does execute the code successfully and gives the final result, which is "false". I tried the same code on the on an online compiler, here, the online compiler gives the result without any warnings.

Any reason for this?

Comment: `if((c>110 && c>120)&&(c<120 && c<200))` there are redundant checks here. If `c` is less than `120`, it is also less than `200`. As, `&&` will check the second expression, if the first one is true, your IDE warns that the second check will always be true.

Comment: Note that it's implementation-defined (i.e. up to the compiler) if `char` is signed or unsigned. If it's signed then its range will be from `-128` to `127` (two's complement), and the comparison against `200` will not behave as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this problem: You define `c` as a `char` which is a `signed char`. The biggest value that a `signed char` can hold is `127`. So no matter the value, `c < 200` is always `true`.

Also, if `c > 120` is `true`, then `c > 110` is also true. The same thing happens. If `c < 120` is `true` then `c < 200` is also `true`.

Also, please do some proper block scope and indentation. If you don't, it will come back to bite you later.

Comment: The first bullet item is a wrong answer—it is not the cause of the compiler message. It could be mentioned as supplementary information, but it should not be presented as the cause of the message.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `c` as a `char`, which is a `signed char` as most compilers do by default. The highest value a `signed char` can take is 127 on common systems. This is **always** less than 200, and the IDE tells you this fact.

*Note: The header file "limits.h" defines minimum and maximum values for standard types. The interesting value is `CHAR_MAX` that equals `SCHAR_MAX` in your case.*

Warnings by an IDE can differ from warnings by compilers, because they are different beasts. Some are "smarter" than others, however, not producing a warning does not mean that a construct is correct.

Comment: Doesn't this correspond to the ASCII values, then, shouldn't the max value be 256? (Am a total newb, sorry if am wasting you time)

Comment: Not at all, since [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a 7 bit code. If you want to use "extended ASCII", you should consider to change the data type. BTW, a maximum value of 256 cannot be stored in an 8 bit variable, you certainly mean 255; and then you need `unsigned char`.

Comment: @user13387446: `unsigned char` should be favored for working with characters in C. The C standard specifies that `unsigned char` values should be used in various places, such as the classification functions in `<ctype.h>`. `char` can be used, but, if it is signed, some character values will be negative. This can be tolerated and worked with, but it requires knowledge and care.

Answer (score 1):

If `c` is larger than 120, it is always larger than 110. Same is true with 120 and 200. Remove the useless comparison and the warning should disappear.

Comment: You are pointing a real issue, but it is not the cause of the diagnostic as the warning only addresses the comparison to 200, not the other redundant one. The fact that `CHAR_MAX < 200` on the target platform seems a better explanation.

Comment: People should not vote up this wrong answer. We know the cause of the error message is the comparison with a value out of bounds of the `char` type, not a redundant comparison shadowed by a previous comparison, because the question says the compiler “specifically shows this only for 200”.